# Misleading documentation for os.open?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
$ ls -l a.txt 
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Mai 13 09:01 a.txt
```

And I do the following:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.open('a.txt', os.O_CREAT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'a.txt'
>>>
```

Where is this documented? Not [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.open), afaik. The only thing specified is the *suggestion* that `os.open` is a wrapper around the C run-time `open` system call, which states:

```
$ man 2 open

RETURN VALUE
       open(), openat(), and creat() return the new file descriptor, or -1 if an error occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately).
```

So, where is the full documentation for `os.open`, including possible exceptions raised and a detailed description of the return value?

Comment: There are languages with formal exception declaration (like Java). Python is not one of them. Do not expect to get a final list of exception from anywhere else than the underlying code and OS. And of cause don't expect them to be documented.

Comment: @KlausD. that is disappointing, specially because exceptions are specified in lots of places in the python documentation. This lack of consistency is a problem. Should I start assuming that the python standard library will raise unexpected exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [**ERRORS** section of `open(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/open.2.en.html#ERRORS):

> ```
> ERRORS
>      The named file is opened unless:
>
>      [EACCES]           The requested access to the file is not allowed,
>                         or search permission is denied for one of the
>                         directories in the path prefix of pathname, or the
>                         file did not exist yet and write access to the 
>                         parent directory is not allowed.
>
>      [..]
> ```

In this list, specific to your OS, you'll find all the different things that might go wrong. To translate that to Python exceptions, you can look at the list of builtin exceptions; all exceptions relevant here should inherit from `OSError`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#os-exceptions

Each individual exception lists what underlying error code it corresponds to, so you can compare that to the `open(2)` list of possible errors. E.g.:

> `exception PermissionError`
>   Raised when trying to run an operation without the adequate access rights - for example filesystem permissions. **Corresponds to errno `EACCES` and `EPERM`.**

In practice most of the time you'll probably want a catch-all `except OSError` block around your `open` call; if you do want to catch only very specific exceptions, you may have to experiment a bit yourself.

Comment: That's nice and good, but what worries me now is that the same could happen to any other function from the python standard library.

Comment: Python indeed isn't very formal about specifying what exceptions it will raise. In many places the documentation does specify, directly or indirectly as it does here, but especially some of the higher abstraction modules will raise all sorts of exceptions from lower level libraries which are *not* all specified in the higher level documentation. They are typically your usual suspects like `ValueError` or `TypeError`, but to be really sure you should test, test and unit test again…

Comment: Having said that, the builtin [error hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) is well structured and logical, and you can typically predict what exceptions might be raised and which ones you're interested in catching merely from that.